# Limit of a recursive sequence with a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have to discuss the limit of the following recursive sequence according to the value of $a$.
$$\begin{cases}a_1=a;\\ a_{n+1}=a_n\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\end{cases}$$
I have considered that for $a=0$ the sequence is identically equal to $0$ $\forall n\geq 1$ and so trivially the limit is $0$.

When $a>0$ I have observed that $a_{n+1}-a_n<0$, since if $a>0$ then $a_n>0$ $\forall n\geq 1$. So the sequence is decreasing and the limit coincides with its infimum that is $0$. Similarly, when $a<0$ the sequence is increasing and the limit is its supremum, which is still $0$.

Is my idea right? I have not shown all steps for proving what I have said in the previous lines, since my doubt is in the scheme adopted and not in the specific proofs about increase or decrease of the sequence.

EDIT: I have tried to find the explicit form of $a_n$. I have obtained:
$a_n=a(\frac{n}{n+1})^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\to \frac{a}{\sqrt{e}}$...so one of my two ideas is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Let $$b_n=a_n\sqrt{n}$$
Then $$b_n=b_{n-1}=\dots=b_1$$
Thus
$$a_n=\frac a {\sqrt n}$$
And the limit is $0$.

Comment: 1) why into the square root you have only $n$? 2) my first idea is correct (that referred to the study of the monotony)?

Comment: I simply plugged the definition of $b_n$ into the recurrence equation you have for $a_n$. This showed that $b_n$ is the constant sequence.

Comment: Sorry but I would like a help to understand my mistakes? Why is not true that $a_n=a(n/(n+1))^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$? And please can you tell me if my work about the monotony works?

Comment: You made a mistake when you delivered the general formula for $a_n$. It should be $a_n=\frac{\sqrt {n-1}}{\sqrt {n}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt {n-2}}{\sqrt {n-1}}\dots \frac{\sqrt 1}{\sqrt {2}}a$ which results into the same formula as me.

Comment: Ok thanks! What's about my first idea of working??

Comment: Regarding the argument on monotony, it is flawed. It's true that for $a>0$, the sequence is decreasing, and since it's positive, this proves that it converges.  But that's not enough to show the limit is $0$.

Comment: Why not? Let's take the case $a>0$. the limit exists and it is $0$ or $-\infty$. The limit must be $0$ since $a_n>0$ and so the sequence cannot go to $-\infty$

Comment: As far as I can tell, you didn't prove the limit is either $0$ or $-\infty$. You need to do it. There are infinitely many positive decreasing sequences that converge to Vanessa other than $0$.

Comment: BTW, if you're satisfied with my answer, please mark it as such.

Comment: $0$ is the only finite possible limit since it is the only fixed point of the function $f(a_n)=a_n\sqrt{n/n+1}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132976/discussion-between-stefan-lafon-and-cely).